# In Gitlab How to Prevent Anyone Including Admin From Pushing?

Tags: gitlab, devops

I am a new Gitlab admin, and I have protected my 'main' branch in a project from anyone pushing, and yet I was still able to push by accident to 'main'.

Why is this? How to prevent anyone including myself as admin from pushing to 'main'?

Protecting a branch and denying access to push still allowed me as an admin to push. So this is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected the "None" option from Allowed to push and merge list?

If you go to the **setting**, then **repository** then expand **protected branches** then select your main branch, and from the **Allowed to merge** list select who can merge in the main branch and select the "None" option from **Allowed to push and merge** list.

This should work fine. Please follow this [gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#for-one-project).

Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: I did that as per my original post. I was still able to push to main. "Protecting a branch and denying access to push still allowed me as an admin to push. So this is not the answer."

Comment: Have you checked the Gitlab group settings? If that project is part of a group and if that group setting is allowing to push admin then changing in the project setting will not work because group settings will override the project settings.